# Question from Rudin Prologue Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

There is the theorem:

If $w$ is a complex number and $w$ $\neq$ $0$ then $w$ $=$ $e^z$ for some $z$.

There is the proof:

if $w$ $\neq$ $0$, put $\alpha$ $=$ $\frac {w}{|w|}$. Then $w$ = $|w|\alpha$.

By the theorem  ( The restriction of exp to the real axis is a monotonically increasing positive function, and $e^x\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$, $e^x\to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$.),  there is a real $x$ such that $|w|$ $=$ $e^x$.
since $|\alpha|$ $=$ $1$, $a$ $=$ $e^{iy}$ for some real $y$(that comes from one theorem) . Hence $w$ $=$ $e^{x+iy}$.
This proves the theorem.

I don't understand why is $|\alpha|$ equal of $1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $|\alpha|=|w/|w||=|w|/|w|=1$. This is called normalisation, sometimes, especially in the context of vectors

Comment: $|\alpha|$ $=$ $\frac {|w|}{||w||}$ . so this last one is equal of $1$? @FShrike how is it possible? we're talking about the length and not simple absolute value

Comment: $|(|w|)|=|w|$, as $|w|$ is a nonnegative real number. The modulus / norm / length / whatever is *multiplicative*: $| ab |=|a|\cdot|b|$. So, $|w/|w||=|w| / |(|w|)| = |w|/|w|=1$ ($|w|\neq0$)